# I have this form, and its not actually sending anything to the php page, could it be the form or php?

Tags: html, forms

I have recently made a website in muse and I extracted the site as html, I've been working on this code for a while adding my php to the sections I need to, even so this specific form, is not actially been sent to the php page that I allocated, this is the site so you can see what I mean.

http://stu391.lccwebtest.co.uk/index.php

```html
<form class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu1975" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php">
  <!-- none box -->
  <input type="file" value="Upload Image" name="Photo">
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu1976" data-required="true">
    <!-- none box -->
    <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1977-4" for="widgetu1976_input">
      <!-- content -->
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="u1977-4_0_content">
      Name:
      </span>
    </label>
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1978-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu1976_input" name="name" tabindex="4"/>
      <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu1976_prompt" for="widgetu1976_input">
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="widgetu1976_prompt_0_content">
      Your Name
      </span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div class="fld-message clearfix grpelem" id="u1979-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p class="shared_content" data-content-guid="u1979-4_0_content">Required</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu1984" data-required="true" data-type="email">
    <!-- none box -->
    <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1985-4" for="widgetu1984_input">
      <!-- content -->
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="u1985-4_0_content">
      Email:
      </span>
    </label>
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1986-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <input class="wrapped-input" type="email" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu1984_input" name="Email" tabindex="5"/>
      <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu1984_prompt" for="widgetu1984_input">
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="widgetu1984_prompt_0_content">
      name@email.com
      </span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div class="fld-message clearfix grpelem" id="u1987-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p class="shared_content" data-content-guid="u1987-4_0_content">Required</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu1994" data-required="true">
    <!-- none box -->
    <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1996-4" for="widgetu1994_input">
      <!-- content -->
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="u1996-4_0_content">
      Username:
      </span>
    </label>
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u1995-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu1994_input" name="Username" tabindex="6"/>
      <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu1994_prompt" for="widgetu1994_input">
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="widgetu1994_prompt_0_content">
      Enter Username
      </span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div class="fld-message clearfix grpelem" id="u1997-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p class="shared_content" data-content-guid="u1997-4_0_content">Required</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu2006" data-required="true">
    <!-- none box -->
    <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u2009-4" for="widgetu2006_input">
      <!-- content -->
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="u2009-4_0_content">
      Password:
      </span>
    </label>
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u2007-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <input class="wrapped-input" type="password" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu2006_input" name="Password" tabindex="7"/>
      <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu2006_prompt" for="widgetu2006_input">
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="widgetu2006_prompt_0_content">
      Enter Password
      </span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div class="fld-message clearfix grpelem" id="u2008-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p class="shared_content" data-content-guid="u2008-4_0_content">Required</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu2011" data-required="true">
    <!-- none box -->
    <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u2013-4" for="widgetu2011_input">
      <!-- content -->
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="u2013-4_0_content">
      Area:
      </span>
    </label>
    <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u2012-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <input class="wrapped-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" id="widgetu2011_input" name="City" tabindex="8"/>
      <label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu2011_prompt" for="widgetu2011_input">
      <span class="actAsPara shared_content" data-content-guid="widgetu2011_prompt_0_content">
      Enter State
      </span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <div class="fld-message clearfix grpelem" id="u2014-4">
      <!-- content -->
      <p class="shared_content" data-content-guid="u2014-4_0_content">Required</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="submit-btn NoWrap grpelem" id="u1988-17" type="submit" value="" tabindex="9"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean framework?

Comment: and thank you donald duck, for changing my spelling errors, it was very helpful

Comment: so does no one know how to fix this

Comment: What specifically seems to go wrong? Is your PHP page named `register.php`? Can we see its contents?